# Mirroring formulas to multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel Workbook with multiple Sheets each using the identical layout, but with different sets of data.  From time to time, I need to vary the way the values are calculated, but I don't want to have to manually edit the formulas on each and every sheet.  Is there a way to have a "Master" sheet the other sheets reference in the Formula cells, but each sheet uses its own data?

Example: On each sheet, I want the cell B3 to calculate "B2+5".  Now I want to edit it to calculate "B2+7", but I don't want to go in and change the B3 cell on each of 20+ Sheets.  I want to go to the "Master" sheet, edit the B3 cell, and have the formula automatically transfer to each of the other sheets.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the change you want to make to a formula. If you want to change the value of a constant, like `=B2+5` to `=B2+7`, and the constant needs to be changed quite often, consider using a named formula instead of a constant.

Open the Name Manager and create a name that describes the nature of your constant, for example "Adjustment" and let it refer to `=5`. Then change all the cells from `=B2+5` to `=B2+Adjustment`. You can now use the Name Manager to change the value of the `Adjustment` name to `=7` and it will apply to all formulas where that name is used.

If you want to change a formula in a more complex way, you'll still need to edit the formulas, but maybe you can apply Find and Replace to make the job faster.

Edit after comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no easy solution for this. If you are changing the nature of cells from data entry to reference or complex formula, that is a change in the data architecture and cannot be easily replicated across hundreds of sheets.

Whenever I see that a file has hundreds of sheets, I'm wondering why they are there in the first place. There may be better approaches in structuring / separating data entry and data presentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want to be able to make more complex changes.  I may want to change the way a value is calculated, for example.  Or to change a cell that was a simple data entry and make it a reference.  My Book may eventually expand to over 100 Sheets..I'd like to be able to edit how a cell is calculated without having to do it every time (and risk missing one)

Comment: I edited my answer.